# Why can't I print X as I use in the inner outer class?

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, kotlin

Why can I not print X? I am trying to use an inner and outer class.

```
class outer {
    val name: String = "kara"
    inner class Inner {
        fun sum(): Int {
            var X = 10 + 11
            return X as Int
        }
    }
}
fun main() {
    val inners = outer().Inner().sum().X: Int
    println(inners)
}
```

Comment: You're probably getting a syntax error where you have `....sum().X: Int`

Comment: How is this related to JavaScript?

Comment: I may be wrong (because I do javascript, not kotlin), but like what @Rafa said, why do you need to do `.X` if the `sum()` method of `Inner` returns an `Int`? Try doing `val inners = outer().Inner().sum()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting a syntax error where you have `....sum().X: Int`
Also,  you can't access X because it is scoped to within the `sum()` function. you can only access the return value of functions. So it should be
`outer().Inner.sum()` to get what you are looking for

Comment: I have tried that I even returned the value. Thanks so much